# Active admin redirects after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

When an admin logs in, it automatically redirects to the main home page (i.e. not the admin dashboard).  I'm not sure why it does this or how to change it...

routes.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :admin_user, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config


  get "guidelines/topic"
  get "guidelines/topichospital"
  get "guidelines/topicspecialty"
  get "guidelines/favourite"
  get "profiles/show"
  get "guidelines/show"

root :to => 'guidelines#index'
```

my application_controller.rb has been changed to redirect after user login (but shouldn't be admin login) - is this the problem?

```
include PublicActivity::StoreController
  protect_from_forgery

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 favourites_path
end

hide_action :current_user
```

Comment: what's in your controller where the `login` action is placed?

Comment: have added from application controller - is that it?  Am using devise

Comment: in the `def after_sign_in_path_for` method you should write instead of `favourites_path` where you want it to redirect you to. I have never used devise, so i'm not sure if this is correct but try to replace the `favourites_path` with `admin_root_path`. Look at all of your routes with rake routes, and change the direction with the `_path` suffix in your method

Comment: but isn't this just redirecting after user login?  I want normal user login to redirect to favouries_path

Comment: Oh, sorry, as I said i have never used devise. Try to find out where the login action for the Admin is and change the redirection path there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Zippie I found the answer.  In admin_controller.rb I added:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     admin_dashboard
end
```

Comment: To do this Rails 4.1 and ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre, use config.root_to in the active_admin initialiser.

Answer (score 3):

I had to do this:

```
class ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    admin_dashboard_path
  end
end
```

to fix the issue.

It also opens some possibilities for customization if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

```
if resource.class == User
  root_path
elsif resource.class == AdminUser
  admin_root_path
else
end
```